# SQL dataset displayed in datagridview Initialization Error C#

Tags: c#, sql, initialization, dataset

I have created a database in SQL and displayed in datagridview windows form application. I have a button for Save. When it clicked, it should save save the
changes.

```
table1BindingSource.EndEdit();
table1TableAdapter.Update(names1DataSet.Table1);
```

But when I run the program and click the Save button it says

```
 table1TableAdapter.Update(names1DataSet.Table1);
```

is not initialized. Please help.

Comment: Are you using DataBinding? If yes, please provide more detail and code to get better answers; it's always good to provide deep details.

Answer (score 0):

For the update you must use the Dataset see [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update?view=net-6.0)

```
table1TableAdapter.Update(names1DataSet);
```